# removing #include causes error

Tags: c++, linker, include, direct3d

I have a class called D3DGraphics in a header file called D3DGraphics.h. I have included d3d9.h and my Graphics file works absolutely file.

However, recently I found a header file which was including D3DGraphics.h when it was not using it, so I removed the

```
#include "D3DGraphics.h"
```

When I did that, the D3DGraphics header / cpp file suddenly forgot all the DirectX definitions and I got loads of errors like IDirect3D9 and D3DCOLOR_XRGB is undefined!? I have used

```
#pragma once
```

in all my header files and I'm pretty sure there is no mutual inclusion so I'm stumped. Why would removing the #include of a file cause that file to stop working!?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably because some other file was including this file, and (accidentally) relying on it being included from the file where you removed it from.

Comment: Surely that wouldn't cause the D3DGraphics file to get errors though?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio there's a compiler option to list all included files, so you can track down problems like this.  It's located at `C/C++.Advanced.Show Includes` in the project properties.

Comment: Ok I tried that but still no luck, no double includes of D3D headers :/

Comment: You're looking for the wrong thing. "Undefined" means that the definitions aren't known when they're first used, not that they're being included multiple times.  If your `D3DGraphics.h` file depends on DirectX defintions, then *it* should `#include` the necessary DirectX header files.

Comment: It does, and it works perfectly. BUT, as soon as I remove the #include D3DGraphics.h from another file, which barely has any code, i get loads of "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'" and "error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed" errors.

Comment: Can you post some more code please? The error that you mentioned is pretty common with h and cpp interaction and it could be an <error type> sort of thing.

Comment: Look at the preprocessed output.

Comment: @JosephPla I could but there is a lot of it, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using header guards instead of `#pragma once`.

i.e.

```
#ifndef D3DGRAPHICS_H
#define D3DGRAPHICS_H

class D3DGraphics...

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who had this problem: I was an idiot. Somewhere in my program I had used
   `#include <d3d.h>`
This caused the directx version to be defined as lower than 9, so in my graphics header when I used `#include <d3d9.h>`
it did not define any directx9 types (facepalm.)